Excel Office.js: How to preserve custom formula text in the formula bar when batch-updating cells?
I’m building an Excel add-in using the Office JavaScript API. I have custom formulas like =PMPBK(...) that work fine if I rely on Excel’s @customfunction approach. The user sees the formula in the formula bar and Excel calls my JavaScript code to get results.
However, I need to batch these formulas for performance. When I manually set:
targetCell.values = [[someResult]];

or
targetCell.formulas = [[originalFormulaString]];
targetCell.values = [[someResult]];

it overwrites the original formula in the formula bar. I want the user to see their typed formula (like =THe_FORMULA(MY_VLAUE)), but the displayed cell value should come from my server.
Question: Is there a way to keep the user’s original formula in the formula bar, while also displaying a manually retrieved result from my backend in the same cell? Or do I have to accept that Excel only supports storing either a formula or a value, but not both?
Any tips or recommended workarounds (like hidden helper sheets) are appreciated. Thanks!

Setting .formulas then .values → The formula is replaced or recalculated.
Restoring the formula after setting the value → Excel overwrites the displayed value on next recalc.


It sounds like Excel is doing what it is supposed to do. It isn't clear how you are implementing batching. Are you familiar with Custom Functions Batchin?
